# TypeScript: is it possible to dynamically change the values of an enum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

is it possible to dynamically change the values of an enum? I have an `enum` like this

```
enum MyEnum{
  Error = "Error",
  Warn = "Warnings"
}
```

I then realized that the values here `Error` and `Warnings` have to dynamically generated by `react-i18next` during the runtime for them to be translated into different languages. So I wonder if there is a way to dynamically plug in the values for the enum. The keys would remain the same all the time.

Comment: Just use an object.

Comment: This sounds like an X Y problem. Are you sure you need to add new values to an enum? What do you mean `react-i18next` needs to generate enum values? This enum is defined by you.

Comment: I agree with @AluanHaddad. If you want to change the values, you really don't want an enum. Also enums are only available in typescript and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well enum in TS are constant and you cannot modify the object once you have declared it. Also, if you are working with internationalisation, using enums are not the best approach, unless you want to translate them every time when a page load or a function gets called.

TS Enum reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html